# Get an array value with dynamic index in struts2

Tags: struts2

I'm trying to get a value from an array into a s:textbox element:
it works if I take a hard coded index like:

```
<s:textarea  value="%{languageHelper.myHauptuebbeschr[0]}" />
```

but when I try to use a dynamic index it doesn'T work:

```
<s:textarea  value="%{languageHelper.myHauptuebbeschr[attr.number]}" />
```

Number is not empty, I can get the value via

```
<s:property value="%{#attr.number}" />
```

So how can I use the number variable as index for my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I first save the value in an addtional variable:

```
<c:set var="myHauptuebbeschr" value="${languageHelper.myHauptuebbeschr[number]}" ></c:set>
```

and then get it via:

```
<s:textarea  value="%{#attr.myHauptuebbeschr}"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't it be:

```
<s:textarea  value="%{languageHelper.myHauptuebbeschr[#attr.number]}" />
```